# A value type " String*" cannot be assigned to an entity type "Course "

Tags: c, data-structures

I have been stuck with this error and cant find any solution to my problem. I have a function (code below) that insert_bts_node.

```
enter code hereBSTNodePtr insert_bst_node(BSTNodePtr self, String *item) {

/* check if found location, then insert */
if (self == NULL) {
    self = malloc(sizeof * self);
    self->course = item;
    //item = strcpy(self->course, item);
    self->left = self->right = NULL;
    create_list(self->course);
    //self->course = create_list();

}

/**
* else if (item < self->course) {
    self->left = insert_bst_node(self->left, item);

}
*/
else if (strcmp(item,self->course)<0){
    self->left = insert_bst_node(self->left, item);

}
else if (strcmp(item,self->course) >0){
    self->right = insert_bst_node(self->right, item);
}

return self;
```

}

The error pops up on **self->course = item**.
Definitions that i am using are down below.

```
typedef char* String;

typedef struct Course {
    String name;
    StudentList students;
} Course;

typedef struct bstNode {
    Course course;
    struct bstNode* left;
    struct bstNode* right;
} *BSTNodePtr;
```

Answer (score 0):

`item` is `String*` type and `self->course` is `struct Course` type, just as error message says.
If you want to assign item to name of course(which is `String` type), you should do `self->course.name = *item`